# join function only echoing 1 product of the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3

I made a model function so it will echo the products that belong to the profile user I clicked on, the thing is only the first product of that user gets echoed. For example I have an account that uploaded a total of 7 products and the function only shows the first product on the page..

This are the model functions:

```
function getdata_aangeboden($user_id){
  $this->db->select("users.*,products.*"); 
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id','left');
  $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 } 

    // Gets a list of multiple users.
 function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("*"); 
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Controller function:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?> 
  <div class="main-gifts">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>">
        <img id="fotos" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product->product_foto_thumb; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="products_discription">
            <h3><?php echo $product->product_naam; ?></h3>
            <div class="ophaal_plaats">
                <p>Plaats: <?php  echo $product->ophaal_plaats; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p> <?php  
                    foreach($userdetail_list as $row){ ?>
              <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row->voornaam;?></td>
               </tr>
                    <?php } ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status">
          </div>
      </div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default cb" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Can someone explain to me why it only shows 1 product and not all the products that belong to the same user_id?
thanks

When I print $products:

```
} ?> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 85 [product_naam] => HIHIHIHI [product_beschrijving] => [ophaal_plaats] => ALLOVER [product_foto] => new_f5cea9c914751e0ad0048800ffec3d05.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_f5cea9c914751e0ad0048800ffec3d05.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-25 [date_updated] => 2017-10-25 [category_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 86 [product_naam] => HUHUUHU [product_beschrijving] => [ophaal_plaats] => NOWHERE [product_foto] => new_ba2430d2b531bc421f27b5f14667cffb.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_ba2430d2b531bc421f27b5f14667cffb.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-25 [date_updated] => 2017-10-25 [category_id] => 4 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 87 [product_naam] => HOHOHO [product_beschrijving] => [ophaal_plaats] => NOIDEA [product_foto] => new_e1dfb9a860859ff882d13435e796578c.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_e1dfb9a860859ff882d13435e796578c.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-25 [date_updated] => 2017-10-25 [category_id] => 7 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 88 [product_naam] => HEHEHE [product_beschrijving] => [ophaal_plaats] => Korea [product_foto] => new_c080495685ed05ab5d4f8a7dcdb8e668.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_c080495685ed05ab5d4f8a7dcdb8e668.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-25 [date_updated] => 2017-10-25 [category_id] => 8 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 89 [product_naam] => ugilh [product_beschrijving] => hjgluhsfkh;sidh fihsdiuhfluisdhauighsudiahguivhadsuihudisahluihvsaduihvluidsahuihv [ophaal_plaats] => Amsterdam [product_foto] => new_c6dd9fa0dc0be0830ed43940b5907115.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_c6dd9fa0dc0be0830ed43940b5907115.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-26 [date_updated] => 2017-10-26 [category_id] => 1 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 93 [product_naam] => 11111 [product_beschrijving] => frfewefwe [ophaal_plaats] => 1111 [product_foto] => new_14de53777d648dcbe31dea26fa031ced.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_14de53777d648dcbe31dea26fa031ced.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-26 [date_updated] => 2017-10-26 [category_id] => 2 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 4 [email] => jeremy@gmail.com [voornaam] => Jeremy [achternaam] => Mathieu [straat] => [huisnummer] => 22 [postcode] => 1223lL [woonplaats] => Rotterdam [wachtwoord] => $2y$10$rO.e4j0dofAUZSWV8sP6yOHYqLzhPkRk9FjBylwbaMMmWRoCBp2oy [beschrijving] => Hallo ik ben Jeremy [geboortedatum] => 2017-06-10 [startdatum] => 2017-06-29 [geslacht] => Man [reset_password_key] => [profiel_foto] => 1498736939jeremy.jpg [product_id] => 94 [product_naam] => hiu;ij [product_beschrijving] => hk;h uihucuhsducuisdhuvsdphvjuisjhuvsudih [ophaal_plaats] => Amsterdam [product_foto] => new_f68becfc0741d3a2300f49ed5bcf58a5.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_f68becfc0741d3a2300f49ed5bcf58a5.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-26 [date_updated] => 2017-10-26 [category_id] => 5 ) )
```

Comment: Your loop is not end properly please check it.

Comment: Its not even started correctly with the missing { after the foreach() . It will only loop once and show the very last entry.

Comment: Are all products associated with users?  If not, only products that are associated with users will be returned unless you use a left or right join

Comment: yes all products are associated with users

Comment: How do i end my foreach loop? when I try endforeach; it gives me an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query as follows

```
function getdata($user_id){
  $this->db->select("products.*,users.*"); 
  $this->db->from('products');
  $this->db->join('users','users.user_id = products.user_id','left');
  $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with my foreach loop? can you check it I dont think I'm ending the foreach loop right

Comment: Foreach loop is good. but i think the query has some error. Could you please `echo $this->db->last_query();die;return $query->result();` edit the function as this and run the query in the phpmyadmin lets see if query has a problem or not

Answer (score 2):

I hope you should declare foreach loop correctly.

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) {
     // print here the product info
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, now you close the for loop. Also you should use lower case for url rather "/Product/details/".

Comment: When I end the foreach loop with this: <?php } ?> it gives me an error unexpected }

Comment: Where you write the loop, in controller or view?

Answer (score 0):

i have found that you have only put the

> tr

tag, but not the

> table

tag, this may cause a issue,so please review my answer below

```
<?php 
  foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="main-gifts">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>">
            <img id="fotos" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product->product_foto_thumb; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="products_discription">
            <h3><?php echo $product->product_naam; ?></h3>
            <div class="ophaal_plaats">
                <p>Plaats: <?php  echo $product->ophaal_plaats; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="aangeboden_door">
                <p> 
                    <table>
                    <?php
                    foreach($userdetail_list as $row){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row->voornaam;?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default cb" value="Cadeau bewerken">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it shows this: SELECT `users`.*, `products`.* FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = '4'

Comment: That is correct right? get all products from user_id = 4 ?

Comment: can you copy that query and run on database tool

Comment: or you can just "print_r(products )"